# Login error using Rebex with SMTP on Office365

Tags: c#, smtp, office365, rebex

I have successfully configurated Office365 environment to send and receive email following these docs:

https://blog.rebex.net/office365-imap-pop3-oauth-unattended

https://blog.rebex.net/office365-ews-oauth-unattended

Now I'm using Rebex library and C# code to check it.

The common part:

**Common**

```
         string[] scopes = new[] {
                  "https://outlook.office365.com/.default", "openid", "email", "profile" 
         };

        // get an instance of 'confidential client application' API
        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecretValue)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .Build();

        // acquire OAuth 2.0 access token from Microsoft 365
        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        string accessToken = result.AccessToken;
```

**EWS version**

```
        using (var client = new Rebex.Net.Ews())
        {
            client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", SslMode.Implicit);
            client.Settings.Impersonation = new EwsImpersonation() { SmtpAddress = emailAddress };
            if (!client.IsAuthenticated)
                client.Login(accessToken, EwsAuthentication.OAuth20);

            var list = client.GetMessageList(EwsFolderId.Inbox);

            client.SendMessage(mail);
            client.Disconnect();
        }
```

It works!

**IMAP version**

```
        using (var client = new Imap())
        {
            client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", SslMode.Implicit);

            string pattern2 = string.Format("user={0}{1}auth=Bearer {2}{1}{1}", emailAddress, '\x1', accessToken);

            string token2 = Convert.ToBase64String(
                  Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pattern2));

            client.Login(token2, ImapAuthentication.OAuth20);
        }
```

It works!

**SMTP version**

```
        using (var client = new Smtp())
        {
            // I tried also outlook.office365.com
            client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", SslMode.Explicit);

            string pattern2 = string.Format("user={0}{1}auth=Bearer {2}{1}{1}", emailAddress, '\x1', accessToken);

            string token2 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pattern2));

            client.Login(emailAddress, token2, Rebex.Net.SmtpAuthentication.OAuth20);

            client.Send(mail);
            client.Disconnect();
        }
```

Smtp login call returns *Authentication unsuccessful (535)*

The Rebex log:

> [date] ERROR Smtp(1)[8] Info:
> Rebex.Net.SmtpException: Authentication unsuccessful
> [foo.foo.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] (535).    in
> Rebex.Net.Smtp.rozhm(String p0, String p1, SmtpAuthentication p2,
> GssApiProvider p3)    in Rebex.Net.Smtp.hcpew(String p0, String p1,
> SmtpAuthentication p2)

Comment: The hostname for Office 365 SMTP is not `outlook.office365.com`.

Comment: I wrote I tried also smtp.office365.com

Comment: when you retrieve the access token, be sure you're passing the `resource` parameter of `https://outlook.office.com` to the token endpoints; and that the account & organisation both allow SMTP authentication.

Comment: @TZHX I posted all the code. Can you explain me the detail of your topic?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing SMTP.Send permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [Any issues?](https://blog.rebex.net/office365-imap-pop3-oauth-unattended#common-issues) section in the mentioned articles. There is written:

> Microsoft 365 does not support app-only authentication for SMTP yet. However, it will still be possible to enable username/password authentication for SMTP after October 1st 2022.

Please note that, when you are configuring your app for unattended access, you have to add some permissions from the `Office 365 Exchange Online` group. There are permissions for EWS, IMAP, POP3, but there are currently no permissions for SMTP.

Hint: If you don't want to use real user's password for SMTP authentication, it is possible to [generate](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944) an `app password` and use it instead.

Comment: Ok. So I can use EWS and Imap class but I cannot use SMTP class (eg Rebex).

Comment: You can use SMTP if:
- you are using basic authentication (username/password)
- you are using OAuth in delegated mode (with user present)

You cannot use SMTP if you are using OAuth in app-only mode (without user present) - this option is not supported by Microsoft.

However, you can use EWS (in app-only mode) to send your email.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Graph API to send emails, but this is not covered by Rebex classes. Note that Graph API is missing couple features, such as signed and encrypted emails, sending MIME larger than 3MB and more.

Comment: Just as note: For files > 3 MB using CreateUploadSession

Comment: As far as we know `CreateUploadSession` can be used to upload mail attachments only (not the message itself). If you know how to upload complete message in MIME format using `CreateUploadSession` please let us know. We are very interested in such possibility. Thank you.